# Angular Universal with Firestore "get()" doesn't work but "valueChanges()" does

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2, angular-universal

I have been trying to make my Angular application to an Angular Universal application which gets the data from Firebase Firestore.

I have been following the guide below:

https://fireship.io/lessons/angular-universal-firebase/

The initial compilation and things work all fine and even when getting the data from Firestore with the help of `valueChanges()` method does the trick.

However if I change `valueChanges()` to `get()` and adjust the required things on the `DocumentSnapshot` it seems that the universal doesn't wait for the data to be fetch and gets rendered.

**TEMPLATE FILE**

```
<div class="desc" *ngIf="(task | async) as ts">
  {{ts.description}}
</div>
```

**WORKING CODE**

```
export class Task {

    colRef: AngularFirestoreCollection;

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
        this.colRef = this.db.collection(this.COL_NAME);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.task = this.colRef.doc(id).valueChanges();
    }
}
```

**NOT WORKING CODE**

```
export class Task {

    colRef: AngularFirestoreCollection;

    constructor(private db: AngularFirestore) {
        this.colRef = this.db.collection(this.COL_NAME);
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.task = this.colRef.doc(id).get().pipe(map(docSnapshot => docSnapshot.data()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @RafaelCerávolo I haven't found a solution for this. I resolved it by building a HTTP functions and then using HttpClient on the Angular side. This solved the issue however not the way I wanted it to happen as it involved writing the functions code as well.

Comment: What I've ended up doing was changing get() by snapshotChanges() and testing isPlataformBrowser() to unsubscribe just after getting the first result on the client side (since piping with first() was also not waiting to render or sometimes hanging indefinitely), and never unsubscribing when on the server side. I don't know the side effects of leaving a snapshotChanges open in the server side, but I hope that angular universal releases all resources after finishing the render process!

Answer (score 0):

`valuechanges()` is a method inside the package `angularFire` and it returns an `Observable` while `get()` method is inside the firestore package and it returns a `Promise`. Therefore you cannot use `pipe` with `get()`

Angularfire:

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#valuechanges

`get()`:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document

Comment: get() is actually a method of `AngularFirestoreDocument` class in the angularFire which returns an Observable.

https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/firestore/document/document.ts

Comment: I see, maybe better open an issue in repository and ask them about the `get()` in AngularFirestoreDocument. Because I'm not sure why it's not documented